# How do I calculate a column of a metric for each unique value of other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have this dataframe:

```
Days since    Year of
last login    registration
1             2010
2             2010
4             2010
1             2010
1             2011
10            2011
```

What is the best way to apply value_counts to the "Days since last login" column so that it is only calculated for each year separately?

I think I could solve it with using `unique()` function and `for` cycle, but I wander if there more elegant solution.

Comment: Please provide me with code to convert input to a DataFrame and express your desired output in a table.

Comment: @PandaKim Is it really that hard to just type? `pd.DataFrame({'dsll': [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 10], 'y': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011]})`

Comment: @ifly6 This is because the structure of the DataFrame is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to apply value_counts to the "Days since last login" column so that it is only calculated for each year separately?

Is what you're looking for not just?

```
>>> df.groupby('y')['dsll'].value_counts()
y     dsll
2010  1       2
      2       1
      4       1
2011  1       1
      10      1
Name: dsll, dtype: int64
```

Your query isn't entirely clear. Posting your attempt would clarify things substantially.